# I am using ng-repeat which populates different drop-downs. How can we give ng-model names dynamically

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

Here is the part of code that will explain the scenario :

```
<tr ng-repeat="ws in popupArray track by $index">

    <td>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="floor" ng-options="item as item.floor for item in floors" ng-click='onFloorChange(item.floor)'>
    <option value=""  selected="selected">Please select a floor</option>
    </td>

    <td>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="cubicle" ng-options="item for item in cubicles">
    <option value=""  selected="selected">Please select a workstation</option>
    </td>

    <td class="text-center">{{ws.cubicleID}}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="deleteEntry($index,ws.cubicleID)">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

Controller  code:

```
    $scope.floors=['GF','1F','2F'];
    $scope.onFloorChange = function(floor)
     {
         $scope.cubicles = [];
         $http.get("retrieve.jsp?floor="+floor).then(function(response) {

                  for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++)
                  {
                    $scope.cubicles.push(response.data[i].CUBICAL);

                  }
                });
     }
```

Here, the dropdowns are populated based on the ng-repeat, but i am not able to provide a unique ng-model to each drop-downs., that is creating problem while seeting up the values of drop-down also while fetching the data of the drop-downs.
The array floors is something that I have defined inside the controller.And popUpArray is diferent one ,that is used for a different purpose.The drop down 2 is populated based on the value of drop down 1.But when I change the values of drop down1,all the values of drop down 2 are getting changed.I want only that row drop-down2 value to get changed

Comment: you need an array of models, try something like `ws.floor`, etc. (extent `popupArray` or create a new one: `someArray[$index].floor`)

Comment: can you explain what arrays of model you are talking about.

Comment: You can make use of `$index` for dynamic `ng-model`, something like this: `ng-model="floor-{{ $index + 1 }}"`.

Comment: @Shashank That syntax ain't working?Any other alternative

Comment: Can you provide slightly more context here?  Your question says that "The drop down 2 is populated based on the value of drop down 1"  One would assume you mean that the `cubicle` dropdown is based on the result of the `floor` dropdown, and that must be occurring in the `onFloorChange` function, but it's not exactly clear. The code for that function would be helpful, as well as the relationship between the `ws` items and the dropdowns that are being displayed, and maybe a sample of the data with the possible values for the dropdowns.

Comment: @Claire , I have added the code. I am calling ng-change to populate drop down 2 based on the value selected in drop down 1

Comment: I have added an answer for the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If we can look at `ws` as the model for each row in the table, it would be very apt to have selected values of floors and cubicles in the same object only. The changed HTML would then be

```
<td>
<!-- The major change here is ng-model=ws.floor; This will make the model unique to each row in the HTML table. Also, ng-change will be fired only after the ng-model is updated. So we can use ws.floor as the argument -->
<select class="form-control" ng-model="ws.floor" ng-options="item as item.floor for item in floors" ng-change='onFloorChange(ws.floor)'>
<option value=""  selected="selected">Please select a floor</option>
</td>

<td>
<!-- The major change here is ng-model=ws.cubicle, which becomes unique to each row in the HTML table -->
<select class="form-control" ng-model="ws.cubicle" ng-options="item for item in cubicles">
<option value=""  selected="selected">Please select a workstation</option>
</td>
<!-- In my opinion, this column for cubicleID can be removed -->
<td class="text-center">{{ws.cubicleID}}</td>
<!-- Major change here is the change in the signature of the deleteEntry method to use the row object's cubicle value and not depend on the $index -->
<td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="deleteEntry(ws.cubicle)">Delete</button></td>
```

Comment: The array floors is something that I have defined inside the controller.And popUpArray is diferent one ,that is used for a different purpose.The drop down 2 is populated based on the value of drop down 1.But when I change the values of drop down1,all the values of drop down 2 are getting changed.I want only that row drop-down2 value to get changed

Comment: Then onFloorChange should take the row object as a parameter and affect only that row object. Meaning, onFloorChange(ws) - as ws is a row object, it should work. Also, do not try to change the items array, as it matters for all the rows. I am not sure, if working only on row object, ws, would work in your case!

Answer (score 0):

Bind the ng-models to the current object (ws) in the popupArray

```
<tr ng-repeat="ws in popupArray track by $index">

    <td>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="ws.floor" ng-options="item as item.floor for item in floors" ng-click='onFloorChange(item.floor)'>
    <option value=""  selected="selected">Please select a floor</option>
    </td>

    <td>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="ws.cubicle" ng-options="item for item in cubicles">
    <option value=""  selected="selected">Please select a workstation</option>
    </td>

    <td class="text-center">{{ws.cubicleID}}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="deleteEntry($index,ws.cubicleID)">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The array floors is something that I have defined inside the controller.And popUpArray is diferent one ,that is used for a different purpose.The drop down 2 is populated based on the value of drop down 1.But when I change the values of drop down1,all the values of drop down 2 are getting changed.I want only that row drop-down2 value to get changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json array looks like:

```
$scope.popupArray = [{
    'id': 101,
    'name': 'Test 1',
    'desc': 'Desc 1',
    'list': [{
        'id': 1001,
        'name': 'List 1001'
    },
    {
        'id': 1002,
        'name': 'List 1002'
    },
    {
        'id': 1003,
        'name': 'List 1003'
    },
    {
        'id': 1004,
        'name': 'List 1004'
    },
    ]
},
{
    'id': 102,
    'name': 'Test 2',
    'desc': 'Desc 2',
    'list': [{
        'id': 2001,
        'name': 'List 2001'
    },
    {
        'id': 2002,
        'name': 'List 2002'
    },
    {
        'id': 2003,
        'name': 'List 2003'
    },
    {
        'id': 2004,
        'name': 'List 2004'
    },
    ]
},
{
    'id': 103,
    'name': 'Test 3',
    'desc': 'Desc 3',
    'list': [{
        'id': 3001,
        'name': 'List 3001'
    },
    {
        'id': 3002,
        'name': 'List 3002'
    },
    {
        'id': 3003,
        'name': 'List 3003'
    },
    {
        'id': 1004,
        'name': 'List 3004'
    },
    ]
},
{
    'id': 104,
    'name': 'Test 4',
    'desc': 'Desc 4',
    'list': [{
        'id': 4001,
        'name': 'List 4001'
    },
    {
        'id': 4002,
        'name': 'List 4002'
    },
    {
        'id': 4003,
        'name': 'List 4003'
    },
    {
        'id': 4004,
        'name': 'List 4004'
    },
    ]
}
];
```

Assign a new array `$scope.modelContainer` of same length as that of `$scope.popupArray`

```
$scope.modelContainer = new Array($scope.popupArray.length);
```

Finally, the dynamic `ng-model` can be given as:

```
<select name="ws.id" ng-model="modelContainer[$index]" ng-options="item.name as item.id for item in ws.list"></select>
```

Have a look at the [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/Ldwmyzgb/).